# Angular 2 - Services consuming others services before call a method

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've this scenario.

backend.json

```
{
"devServer": "http://server1/'",
"proServer" : "http://server2/'",
"use" :  "devServer"
}
```

global.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
constructor(private _http: Http){}
getBackendServer(){
    return this.server = this._http.get('./backend.json')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
}
}
```

And I've this other service: search.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {GlobalService} from '../services/global.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
server;
constructor( private _http: Http, private gs: GlobalService ) {
    this.server = gs.getBackendServer().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.server = data[data.use];
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);  
        }
    );
}
DoGeneralSearch(params:Search){
    console.log(this.server);
    let options = this.buildOptions(params);
    return this._http.get(this.server + 'room/search', options)
     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
} 
}
```

What I want to do: Looks obvious: I want to keep the information regarding the URL of the backend server in a JSON file - And the global service should return the server so this can be used in any method of the search service.

The problem is: the DoGeneralSearch() method executes before the global service is capable to resolve the task to read the JSON file and return the result. So, I've a this.server = Subscriber {isUnsubscribed: false, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false…} instead the result itself.

I need to find some how to prevent the method DoGeneralSearch be executed just after resolved the this.server variable.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

I think that you could preload such hints at the application startup. For this, you could leverage the `APP_INITIALIZER` service. The application will wait for the returned promise to be resolved before actually starting.

Here is a sample:

```
provide(APP_INITIALIZER, {
  useFactory: (service:GlobalService) => () => service.load(),
  deps:[GlobalService, HTTP_PROVIDERS], multi: true
})
```

The `load` method would like something like that:

```
load():Promise<Site> {
  var promise = this.http.get('config.json').map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
  promise.then(config => this.devServer = config.devServer);
  return promise;
}
```

Then you can directly use the `devServer` (synchronously)...

See this issue on github for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047

Comment: Excellent hint on `APP_INITIALIZER`! Finally, the 'how to pause the app before initialization' question from AngularJS days got a fair answer.

Comment: Hi, I have done this approach but when I debug the promise `service.load()` from the `APP_INITIALIZER` provider, It always return undefined. I have verified that the `load` method returns a value in the `GlobalService` but this module seems to be loaded at the end of the application loading process.

Comment: Also, using [@nglibs\config](https://github.com/nglibs/config) in your project, that will provide you required config data from backend.json which got resolved during application initalization

Comment: In APP_INITIALIZER service i need to make two HTTP call  from various services. Is there any way to initialize