# Angular 2 Resolve Service Before Bootstrap

Tags: angular

http://plnkr.co/edit/yhQQZxTxB8ZVFysqO6lP?p=preview

How can i ensure my AuthService is resolved before AppComponent loads?

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {App} from './app';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {provide, enableProdMode, APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core';

bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
provide("isLoggedIn", { useFactory: (auth:AuthService) => () => auth.login(), deps:[HTTP_PROVIDERS], multi: true }),
])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127741/angular-2-services-consuming-others-services-before-call-a-method

Answer (score 0):

You can use APP_INITIALIZER token to provide your authFactory:

```
//main entry point
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {App} from './app';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {provide, enableProdMode, APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core';

export function authFactory(auth: AuthService){
    return auth.login()
}

bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (auth),
        deps: [AuthService],
        multi: true
    }
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```