# Resolve a value from service while bootstrapping

Tags: typescript, angular

While Angular2 documentation is not complete yet, anyone can point me to the reight direction with the most elegant solution how to resolve the value from a service in advance while bootstrapping and inject it into multiple components?

Right now I same this situation:

```
class ValueComponent implements OnChanges {
    public constructor(private valueService: ValueService) {
    }

    public ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.valueService.getValues().subscribe((values: ValueModel[]) => {
            // The whole component login must be here because only here the "values"
            // are available. It becomes a mess it the same service is used
            // in multiple components.
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible call `valueService.getValues()` in `app.ts` and change the component into something like this:

```
class ValueComponent implements OnChanges {
    public constructor(private values: ValueModel[]) {
    }

    public ngOnChanges(): void {
        // Use this.values without calling the service
    }
}
```

PS. `valueService.getValues()` returns a collection which (almost) never changes, but should not be "hard-coded" into the code.

Comment: Do you use any async operation to create the valueService or this is initializes on bootstrap??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127741/angular-2-services-consuming-others-services-before-call-a-method