# Reading static files in angular2 as string

Tags: node.js, http, angular, angular2-template

I have an angular2 component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    template: `
        <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
    `;
})
export class demoComponent {
    @Input() step: string;

    private content: string = '';

    ngOnInit () {
        if (this.step === "foo") {
            this.content = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to use some logic to decide on the most appropriate template to render. I have a series of static html files served by express on myDomain.com/templates. So I need to be able to "read" `./templates/xyz.html` into a string in my ng2 component. Similarly to the `fs.ReadFileSync` API in nodeJS. How can I do this? HTTP call? file reader?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't read synchronously static files since they rely on an asynchronous API of the browser.

That being said, you could leverage a service to load all your resources and wait for this service to have loaded everything before starting your application. The `APP_INITIALIZER` service allows you to do that.

Here is a sample:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (service:GlobalService) => () => service.load(),
    deps:[GlobalService, HTTP_PROVIDERS], multi: true
  }
]);
```

The load method would like something like that:

```
load():Promise<Site> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('somestaticfile.html')
      .map(res => res.text()    })
      .subscribe(text => {
        this.staticContent = text;
      });
  });
}
```

You can then use within your application the `staticContent` property synchronously:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo',
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
  `
})
export class demoComponent {
  @Input() step: string;

  private content: string;

  constructor(service:GlobalService) {
    this.content = service.staticContent;
  }
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 - Services consuming others services before call a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127741/angular-2-services-consuming-others-services-before-call-a-method/38128065#38128065)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. In my application, I am only using this "demo" component in a subcomponent, which for most users will not get used, so I believe using this in the bootstrap will hold up every user whether they use the demo component or not? If that's correct, is there a way to only "hold up" the component that `<demo>` will be used in?