# Is it possible to bootstrap ng2+ app manually from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to bootstrap NG2+ app manually from jquery / javascript code?

I need something like we do in TypeScript:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: this line will work in JavaScript as well, also read [How to manually bootstrap an Angular application](https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-manually-bootstrap-an-angular-application-9a36ccf86429)

Comment: Is there a way to bootstrap module from jQuery code on my page? I'm trying to use the code I've provided above, but have errors..

Comment: I believe this will be a pretty big answer with lots of nuances... As I said, the line you referenced will work in a browser regardless from it's executed

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: sorry, your question is too broad, try to make it specific

Comment: I have an angular app. And before start the ng2+ app I want to make some checks like auth, tokens etc.. so I need to quickly check user permissions (via javascript / jquery), then bootstrap ng2+ app if all is fine. At least I want to know if that possible.. :)

Comment: Yeah, it is possible

Comment: Do you know how or where I can read about that?

Comment: create a basic plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation is being approached from wrong end.

In order to do that, `platformBrowserDynamic` and `AppModule` should be exposed to global scope, and they aren't. While it is possible to load Angular as UMD modules and have it as `ng` global, this would result in 2 copies of Angular, and `AppModule` would still be unreachable.

It's possible by exposing a function to global scope:

```
window.bootstrapApp = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But considering that the objective is to *quickly check user permissions* with non-Angular code, the right place to do this is still `main.ts`. And the preferable way to postpone application initialization is to do checks on bootstrap with [`APP_INITIALIZER` provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822351/3731501).