# control UI rendering in angualr2

Tags: angular

To create my initial screen I need to make some calls to the services and the basis of response I need to make changes in my UI. Now challenge is that I don't want my view to be render before I get the response from UI.

Is there any way to prevent UI to be render and after getting response from services I can ask UI to get render after setting my values?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [lifecycle documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), there's no way to place a hook before the rendering, because if you do it in `ngOnChanges`, it will be called at every change.

I don't know why you want it before the view renders, but this is a false problem. Angular2 exists to be able to manage your view at any time, so even if it's rendered, using tools like `*ngIf`, `*ngSwitchCase`, you can edit your view at any time.

You should probably bind your logic in `ngOnInit` method, and make it change variables in your component so your view gets updated as soon as it has the datas.

Else, if you realy want the view to be rendered only when the service's promise is finished, you can wrap your component's template in a `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="init">
...
...
...
</div>
```

And then once the promise is finished, you can set `init` to true:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit{

    init:boolean=false;

    constructor(private service:FooService){}

    ngOnInit():void{
        service.bar(...).then(() => 
            {
                ...
                this.init = true;
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you effort. I am rendering my menu items on the basis of response form the service. When initially view loads before response from services, user is not able to see the right view. Yes it will change once response will be there and *ngIf will perform its task. It will look weird when menu items will change at runtime. So I want everything available before UI rendering.

But yes, your solution will help me. Let me know if you have any batter idea otherwise I'll accept this answer.

Comment: as i said the purpose of angular2 is to make view dynamic, so the best solution for you is to edit your design the way it can be less weird while waiting for the service response.

Answer (score 0):

If it concerns only your intial screen, you should look at Thierry Templier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128065/2459831) on a similar issue : waiting for an async service before rendering the app.

If this page is load by the router, you can use Angular router [resolve guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) to wait for some async call before rendering the component targeted by the route.